# SelectItem with property multiple select

Tags: smartgwt

I´m using the SelectItem component with configuration:

```
private SelectItem nElementsCombo;
nElementsCombo = new SelectItem();
nElementsCombo.setMultiple(true);
nElementsCombo.setMultipleValueSeparator("|");
```

In the combo the elements selected are shown item_selected_1|item_selected_2|item_selected_3
but when I do:

```
nElementsCombo.getValueAsString()
```

Return item_selected_1,item_selected_2,item_selected_3 and I´d like item_selected_1|item_selected_2|item_selected_3

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

from the javadoc :`If this item is displaying multiple values, this property will be the string that separates those values for display purposes.` Display purpose
I don't catch it, can you replace in your returned string the comma by the pipe ..... !!!

Answer (score 0):

As per Alain's answer, `MultipleValueSeparator` is only for display purpose.

Means, when you select multiple values from `picklist` & then when the `picklist` is hidden on blur (focus lost) of multi select item, the selected values are displayed as a string separated by comma(default). This display can be changed by `MultipleValueSeparator`. But not the one you get by `multiSelectItem.getValueAsString()`.

Also I don't think, there's any provision in SmartGWT API which fulfills your requirement, as of now.